# Handle input of more than one character

Tags: javascript

I want to give numbers to letters of the alphabet. The problem is I don't know how to handle more than one letter in the same value; for example letter "A":1 "E":5 and "D":4 should  return 154 but in my code return gives only the number of the last letter.

```js
var alpha =[
  {   
    "A":1,  
    "B":2,  
    "C":3,   
    "D":4,   
    "E":5,  
    "F":6,  
    "G":7,  
    "H":8,  
    "I":9,  
    "J":10, 
    "K":11, 
    "L":12,
    "M":13,
    "N":14,
    "O":15,
    "P":16,
    "Q":17,
    "R":18,
    "S":19,
    "T":20,
    "U":21,
    "V":22,
    "W":23,
    "X":24,
    "Y":25,
    "Z":26,
  }
];

function bin(letter){

  for (var i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++){
      if(alpha[i].hasOwnProperty(letter)){
        return alpha[i][letter];
      }
  }

}

bin("R");bin("E");
```

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you should look into [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

Comment: Please edit the question and title, it's a little hard to understand.

Comment: what gonna be more easy for understud ?

Comment: So you want to do `bin(AED)` and have the function return `154`?

Comment: Also, why is alpha an object inside an array. Why isn't alpha just the object?

Comment: Just in case you plan to actually use this for some real purpose, you should note that "AED" and "OD" would both return the same value 154...

Comment: yes exactly Andy i wanna bin (AED) give me 154

Comment: not only AED every letter of alphabet give me diffrent number ABC = 123

Answer (score 5):

You could take the string, split it for an array of characters and use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with a radix of `36`, where you get a value for the letter. Later join the result for a single string.

```js
var string = 'aed',
    result = string
        .split('')
        .map(c => parseInt(c, 36) - 9)
        .join('');
        
console.log(result);
```

Even shorter version with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
var string = 'aed',
    result = Array.from(string, c => parseInt(c, 36) - 9).join('');
        
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's implied here, but might be worth mentioning this removes the need for the alpha object completely. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no real reason for that `alpha` object to be in an array:

```
var alpha = {   
  "A":1,  
  "B":2,  
  "C":3,   
  "D":4,   
  "E":5
  ...
}
```

**ES5**

Create an empty output variable. Then iterate over the letters adding each one that maps to an `alpha` value to the output variable. Then just return the output variable.

```
function bin(letters) {
  var out = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
    out += alpha[letters[i]]
  }
  return out;
}

bin("AED"); // 154
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sd46ee8b/)**

**ES6**

More concise: makes the string iterable (spread operator), and then maps over the alpha properties, joining up and returning the mapped at the end.

```
function bin(letters) {
  return [...letters].map(letter => alpha[letter]).join('');
}

bin("AED"); // 154
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6a87uew8/1/)**

Comment: Both demos work. Look in the console for the result.

Answer (score -1):

Here are JavaScript and ES6 code sample

```
function bin(str){
    var result = '';
  for(i=0;i < str.length; i++)
   result += parseInt(str[i], 36) -9;
  return result; 
}

function binES(str){
    return [...str].map(letter => parseInt(letter, 36) - 9).join('');
}

console.log(bin('AED'));
console.log(binES('AED'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/of6grgvu/2/

Comment: Did you just nick code from both mine and Nina's answers to make your own?

Comment: Ha ha, if you feel like that I am sorry. However has to be use for loop in JS core and map method in ES to perform this logic.